# Incorrect order of execution by ScheduledThreadPoolBasedExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading

I use ScheduledThreadPoolBasedExecutor to schedule and execute callable.
According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html): it executes tasks with given delay or (if delays are equal) in FIFO order. It even contains AtomicLong sequencer inside the implementation for this purpose.

I wrote the test which submits a lot of tasks calculating prime numbers.

```
public class MyCallable implements Callable<Boolean> {
    private static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private final long prNumber;
    private long callNanoTime;
    private LocalDateTime callLocalDateTime;
    private boolean isCalled = false;

    public MyCallable(long number) {
        this.prNumber = number;
    }

    public Boolean call() {
        callNanoTime = System.nanoTime();
        callLocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        isCalled = true;
        return isPrime(this.prNumber);
    }

    public boolean isCalled() {..}

    public long getCallNanoTime() {..}

    public LocalDateTime getCallLocalDateTime() {..}

    private boolean isPrime(long n) {..}
}
```

I submit tasks this way:
1) Get interval (2sec from now to 6 sec from now)
2) Generate 4000 tasks and schedule them with uniform distribution (each millisecond actually)

I sorted callables by scheduled time and checked that callNanoTime is non-increasing (obviously it must be true) but in fact no, my test output results like:

```
Callable scheduled to: '2018-01-28T14:04:13.866' was called in: '61665400763727', but callable scheduled to: '2018-01-28T14:04:13.868' was called in: '61665397242047'
```

In fact, callable scheduled to the later time was executed before. If I increase grain size (let it be 5-10 ms between tasks) everything is fine.

Initialization and scheduling:

```
public class ScheduledThreadPoolBasedExecutor implements Executor {
    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;
    private AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong(0);

    public ScheduledThreadPoolBasedExecutor() {
        scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void schedule(Callable callable, LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
        long value = counter.incrementAndGet();
        if (value % 100 == 0) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Schedule callable #%s", value));
        }
        long delay = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(LocalDateTime.now(), localDateTime);
        scheduledExecutorService.schedule(callable, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

Is this 1-3ms inconsistency caused by OS and ScheduledThreadPoolBasedExecutor doesn't guarantee order for such times? Or I use it incorrectly?

Comment: Small update: I've found out that everything works fine with tasks scheduled in order of increasing of desired execution time. Collections.shuffle leads to failed test.